# Where should I use the 'computeS' (or 'computeP') function when using Repa arrays?

Tags: haskell

I have some data in a Repa array and this array is passed through a lot of functions that process the array in some way. Almost all the functions have the type `Array D DIM2 a -> Array D DIM2 a` so I just composite them altogether and apply the composite function to my initial array.

When I do this, the program runs really slow. However, when I insert the `computeS` function throughout my composite function, the code speeds up drastically. I assume this is not the intended way to work with repa arrays. What might the issue be?

Answer (score 0):

Do your functions use some elements of their input arrays more than once? In those cases it is usually better to run `computeS`/`computeP` first so they are computed only once.